# c# .net Core OracleDataReader check count in results

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-core

I know only one way how to `count` rows in results after `ExecuteReader` with this code:

```
while (er.Read()) {
  count++;
}
```

How can I check with no `while`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.

Long answer: `ExecuteReader` returns a forward-only sequential stream iterator, each time you advance one position you will point to and read one record until it reaches the end of the available data. Therefore it is impossible to know how many records you have until you have read all of them.

Here is a solution that may work for you, though.

Imagine you want to run this simple query: `select * from Users`

Even if you run this in your Oracle database directly, you won't know how many records you have until the query is executed. If you wanted to know the number of records you would use a count query, something like `select count(*) from Users`.

You can do the same using c#:

```
int count = 0;

using (var conn = new OracleConnection("Some connection string"))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {    
        cmd.CommandText = "select count(*) from users";
        count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }

    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from users";
        using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read()) {
                [...]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is Count() very fast or does this have the effect of slowing down your code by 50% since you are essentialy doing the (almost) same request twice?

Comment: count is extremely fast, it will not slow down your code by 50%. It is much faster than iterating the results of the select to count each row.  You can measure it with a StopWatch if you are curious. https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: By the way, you could execute both queries at the same time but I don't see any advantage for this particular example, check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511664/mysql-select-and-count-in-same-query

Comment: For my particular use: Times are 250 ms for the count and 550 ms for the actual query (returning about 50000 records). Maybe for millions of record the difference is bigger. Still plenty fast for my use.

Answer (score 2):

You could load your results into a `DataTable` and get the row count of of it:

```
using(var dt = new DataTable()) 
{
   dt.Load(er); //assuming er is the OracleDataReader
}
```

Now you can read the rowCount with `dt.Rows.Count`.